# Как изменить html с помощью javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
document.classList.remove("__sale");
```

```html
<li class="it grid_li __double">
  <div class="gift-card __ru __live __large __sale __no-frame" aria-label="Подарок">
    <li class="it grid_li __double">
      <div class="gift-card __ru __live __large __free __no-frame" aria-label="Подарок"></div>
    </li>
  </div>
</li>
```

полный путь

Мне нужно удалить класс `.__sale` через JavaScript, как я могу это сделать?

Comment: Даже если не париться с запятыми, то хотя бы чётко формулировать мысль. Что именно удалить надо?

Comment: как смог так и описываю просто учусь и хочу разобраться

Comment: Для того чтобы удалить класс у элемента, нужно обратиться к конкретному элементу, а не к документу. Посмотрите [примеры](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B)

Comment: а как найти конкретный документ? через html

Comment: [Поиск элементов документа в JavaScript](https://itchief.ru/javascript/get-elements)

Comment: @Иван Вам же уже дали ответ на вопрос.

Comment: @Иван актуален ли ваш вопрос?

Answer (score 1):

У вас не обозначен объект для которого вы хотите убрать стили, его можно найти разными способами, например, `.querySelectorAll()` или `getElementsByClassName()`.

Добавил CSS для видимости:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.__sale')[0].classList.remove('__sale')
```

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #aaa;
}
.__sale {
  background-color: #2a2;
}
```

```html
<li class="it grid_li __double">
  <div class="gift-card __ru __live __large __sale __no-frame" aria-label="Подарок">
    <li class="it grid_li __double">
      <div class="gift-card __ru __live __large __free __no-frame" aria-label="Подарок"></div>
    </li>
  </div>
</li>
```